# How to get value from html response in Gatling

Tags: gatling, scala-gatling

I am trying to get a value from HTML response using Gatling.
Something like

```
<span>
    <input type="hidden" id="Id" name="userId" value="some value"/>
```

I want to ge the "value" with

```
.check(xpath("xpath from browser").find.is("value").saveAs("userId"))
```

But this does not work. How can I get that?

Comment: is that the literal .check statement? What is "xpath from browser" for?

Answer (score 2):

I haven't used xpath checks much, but you can probably achieve the desired result with the css check

```
.check(css("#Id","value").saveAs("userId"))
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [gatling documentation](https://gatling.io/docs/gatling/reference/current/core/check/)

> XPath only works on well-formed XML documents, which HTML is not.

> If you’re looking for path based engine for parsing HTML documents, please have a look at our CSS selectors support.

Another option may be regex.